# How can I map my fetched data to card component

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm building a quiz app and using some API to fetch data, the response that I get back after making a GET request is something like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 910,
        "question": "What used to be called a minion in Kubernetes cluster?",
        "description": null,
        "answers": {
            "answer_a": "A component of the master node.",
            "answer_b": "A monitoring engine used widely in Kubernetes.",
            "answer_c": "Docker container service.",
            "answer_d": "A worker node.",
            "answer_e": null,
            "answer_f": null
        },
        "multiple_correct_answers": "false",
        "correct_answers": {
            "answer_a_correct": "false",
            "answer_b_correct": "false",
            "answer_c_correct": "false",
            "answer_d_correct": "true",
            "answer_e_correct": "false",
            "answer_f_correct": "false"
        },
        "correct_answer": null,
        "explanation": null,
        "tip": null,
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Kubernetes"
            }
        ],
        "category": "DevOps",
        "difficulty": "Medium"
    },
    {
        "id": 1019,
        "question": "Is Kubernetes open-source?",
        "description": null,
        "answers": {
            "answer_a": "True",
            "answer_b": "False",
            "answer_c": null,
            "answer_d": null,
            "answer_e": null,
            "answer_f": null
        },
        "multiple_correct_answers": "false",
        "correct_answers": {
            "answer_a_correct": "true",
            "answer_b_correct": "false",
            "answer_c_correct": "false",
            "answer_d_correct": "false",
            "answer_e_correct": "false",
            "answer_f_correct": "false"
        },
        "correct_answer": null,
        "explanation": null,
        "tip": null,
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Kubernetes"
            }
        ],
        "category": "DevOps",
        "difficulty": "Easy"
    },
    {
        "id": 1010,
        "question": "While starting minikube, a configuration file, gets created by default inside what directory on Linux?",
        "description": null,
        "answers": {
            "answer_a": "/tmp",
            "answer_b": "/home/user/.kube",
            "answer_c": "/root",
            "answer_d": "/home/user",
            "answer_e": null,
            "answer_f": null
        },
        "multiple_correct_answers": "false",
        "correct_answers": {
            "answer_a_correct": "false",
            "answer_b_correct": "true",
            "answer_c_correct": "false",
            "answer_d_correct": "false",
            "answer_e_correct": "false",
            "answer_f_correct": "false"
        },
        "correct_answer": null,
        "explanation": null,
        "tip": null,
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Kubernetes"
            }
        ],
        "category": "DevOps",
        "difficulty": "Medium"
    },
    {
        "id": 962,
        "question": "Which of the following are true for a pod in Kubernetes?",
        "description": null,
        "answers": {
            "answer_a": "A Pod represents processes running on your Cluster",
            "answer_b": "Pods are the simplest units in the Kubernetes object model that you create or deploy",
            "answer_c": "A pod is the same as a container",
            "answer_d": "You can have only 1 container running in 1 pod",
            "answer_e": null,
            "answer_f": null
        },
        "multiple_correct_answers": "true",
        "correct_answers": {
            "answer_a_correct": "true",
            "answer_b_correct": "true",
            "answer_c_correct": "false",
            "answer_d_correct": "false",
            "answer_e_correct": "false",
            "answer_f_correct": "false"
        },
        "correct_answer": null,
        "explanation": null,
        "tip": null,
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Kubernetes"
            }
        ],
        "category": "DevOps",
        "difficulty": "Medium"
    },
    {
        "id": 1018,
        "question": "Which Process Validates And Configures Data For The Api Objects Like Pods, Services?",
        "description": null,
        "answers": {
            "answer_a": "kube-apiserver process validates and configures data for the api objects.",
            "answer_b": "kube-apiserver process validates and configures data for the gui objects.",
            "answer_c": "kube-apiserver process validates and configures data for the cli objects.",
            "answer_d": null,
            "answer_e": null,
            "answer_f": null
        },
        "multiple_correct_answers": "false",
        "correct_answers": {
            "answer_a_correct": "true",
            "answer_b_correct": "false",
            "answer_c_correct": "false",
            "answer_d_correct": "false",
            "answer_e_correct": "false",
            "answer_f_correct": "false"
        },
        "correct_answer": null,
        "explanation": null,
        "tip": null,
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Kubernetes"
            }
        ],
        "category": "DevOps",
        "difficulty": "Easy"
    },
    {
        "id": 966,
        "question": "What is the purpose of a ReplicaSet?",
        "description": null,
        "answers": {
            "answer_a": "To prevent clones from invading other clusters",
            "answer_b": "To monitor and respond to environmental latency",
            "answer_c": "To maintain a stable set of replica Pods running at any given time",
            "answer_d": "To create and maintain volumes",
            "answer_e": null,
            "answer_f": null
        },
        "multiple_correct_answers": "false",
        "correct_answers": {
            "answer_a_correct": "false",
            "answer_b_correct": "false",
            "answer_c_correct": "true",
            "answer_d_correct": "false",
            "answer_e_correct": "false",
            "answer_f_correct": "false"
        },
        "correct_answer": null,
        "explanation": null,
        "tip": null,
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Kubernetes"
            }
        ],
        "category": "DevOps",
        "difficulty": "Easy"
    },
    {
        "id": 1052,
        "question": "What does 'become: yes' mean in Ansible playbooks?",
        "description": null,
        "answers": {
            "answer_a": "It means that the command must be retried until it succeeds",
            "answer_b": "It means that the service needs to be started once installed",
            "answer_c": "It means that the worker node should become a manager node",
            "answer_d": "It means that we would run all commands as root",
            "answer_e": null,
            "answer_f": null
        },
        "multiple_correct_answers": "false",
        "correct_answers": {
            "answer_a_correct": "false",
            "answer_b_correct": "false",
            "answer_c_correct": "false",
            "answer_d_correct": "true",
            "answer_e_correct": "false",
            "answer_f_correct": "false"
        },
        "correct_answer": "answer_a",
        "explanation": null,
        "tip": null,
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "DevOps"
            }
        ],
        "category": "DevOps",
        "difficulty": "Easy"
    },
    {
        "id": 1017,
        "question": "What Is The Use Of Kube-controller-manager?",
        "description": null,
        "answers": {
            "answer_a": "kube-controller-manager embeds the core control loop which is a non-terminating loop that regulates the state of the system.",
            "answer_b": "kube-controller-manager embeds the core control loop which is a terminating loop that regulates the state of the system.",
            "answer_c": null,
            "answer_d": null,
            "answer_e": null,
            "answer_f": null
        },
        "multiple_correct_answers": "false",
        "correct_answers": {
            "answer_a_correct": "true",
            "answer_b_correct": "false",
            "answer_c_correct": "false",
            "answer_d_correct": "false",
            "answer_e_correct": "false",
            "answer_f_correct": "false"
        },
        "correct_answer": null,
        "explanation": null,
        "tip": null,
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Kubernetes"
            }
        ],
        "category": "DevOps",
        "difficulty": "Medium"
    },
    {
        "id": 922,
        "question": "What is the role of kube-apiserver and kube-scheduler?",
        "description": null,
        "answers": {
            "answer_a": "The kube – apiserver follows the scale-out architecture and, is the front-end of the master node control panel.",
            "answer_b": "The kube – apiserver follows the scale-out architecture and, is the back-end of the master node control panel.",
            "answer_c": null,
            "answer_d": null,
            "answer_e": null,
            "answer_f": null
        },
        "multiple_correct_answers": "false",
        "correct_answers": {
            "answer_a_correct": "true",
            "answer_b_correct": "false",
            "answer_c_correct": "false",
            "answer_d_correct": "false",
            "answer_e_correct": "false",
            "answer_f_correct": "false"
        },
        "correct_answer": null,
        "explanation": null,
        "tip": null,
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Kubernetes"
            }
        ],
        "category": "DevOps",
        "difficulty": "Medium"
    },
    {
        "id": 923,
        "question": "What is ETCD?",
        "description": null,
        "answers": {
            "answer_a": "Etcd is written in Go programming language and is a distributed key-value store used for coordinating between distributed work.",
            "answer_b": "Etcd is written in Python programming language and is a distributed key-value store used for coordinating between distributed work.",
            "answer_c": "Etcd is written in C++ programming language and is a distributed key-value store used for coordinating between distributed work.",
            "answer_d": null,
            "answer_e": null,
            "answer_f": null
        },
        "multiple_correct_answers": "false",
        "correct_answers": {
            "answer_a_correct": "true",
            "answer_b_correct": "false",
            "answer_c_correct": "false",
            "answer_d_correct": "false",
            "answer_e_correct": "false",
            "answer_f_correct": "false"
        },
        "correct_answer": null,
        "explanation": null,
        "tip": null,
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Kubernetes"
            }
        ],
        "category": "DevOps",
        "difficulty": "Easy"
    }
]
```

when I try to log the `response.data` it works good but when I try to log the question of my first element with `console.log(ques[0])` it doesn't works. Here is my code :

```
const [ques, setQues] = useState([]);
    const loadedQues = [];

    
    const fetch = async() => {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://quizapi.io/api/v1/questions?
        apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_QUIZ_API_KEY}
        &limit=10
        &category=DevOps`
        )
        let rawData = response.data;
        rawData.map((item)=>{loadedQues.push(item)});
    }
    useEffect(()=>{ 
        try{
            fetch();
            setQues(loadedQues);    
            console.log(ques[0]);
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: Hey I found a question similar as yours. follow this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67091739/how-to-fetch-an-array-of-objects-and-render-it-in-the-component-as-a-normal-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67091739/how-to-fetch-an-array-of-objects-and-render-it-in-the-component-as-a-normal-text)

Answer (score 0):

In the `useEffect` hooks you are calling `fetch` function before you setting the value of `ques` state. And **fetch is an **async function** and their result might not be available when the `setQues` is call to update the state with the value of **loadedQues** which can still empty when `setQues` is called.

You should update the `fetch` to update the `qest` state when data is available like this

```
const [ques, setQues] = useState([]);

const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(//);
    
    /*
    No need to loop over the response.data as It's an array of data it can be set as value of ques state
    */
    setQues(response.data);
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [])
```

You can call `setQues` inside of the `fetchData` function to update directly the state.

No Need to define the `const loadedQues = []` as the value of the API call is directly pass to the state setter

> **fetch** is a javascript keyword [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

so you must avoid using javascript keyword as name of variables.

with this whenever the data from the API call is available It will trigger the update of the `ques` state which will by the way trigger the component rerender

Comment: Hey @Yves I tried your approach but I can't but it doesn't solved my problem.

Comment: Add `console.log(ques)` just bellow `setQuest` to display data returned by the API call